Galois group of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ over $\mathbb{C}(t+t^{-1})$
I was asked to determine the Galois group for the following extensions:
first $\mathbb{C}(t+t^{-1})\subset \mathbb{C}(t)$
and then $\mathbb{C}(t^n+t^{-n})\subset \mathbb{C}(t)$ for a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now I can see the Galois group is not trivial since the automorphism that sends $t$ to $t^{-1}$ is the identity for $\mathbb{C}(t+t^{-1})$ and as such is in the Galois group. Now for the first extension, we can find the minimal polynomial for the element $t$ which is $x^2-(t+t^{-1})x+1$. I am not entirely sure whether this is enough to prove that Galois group is just $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm mainly having trouble with the second extension. We also have another automorphism which is the identity on $\mathbb{C}(t+t^{-1})$ namely the one that sends $t$ to $\zeta_n t$ with $\zeta_n$ the root of unity. However I don't really see how to use this to determine the Galois group similarly we can also find a polynomial (I'm not sure whether it is the minimal one) for which $t$ is a root, namely, $x^{2n}-(t^n+t^{-n})x^n+1$. Any tips on how to proceed?

Your observations prove that the degree of $\mathbb C(t)/\mathbb C(t^n + t^{-n})$ is at most $2n$, and that it has at least $2n$ automorphisms (the dihedral group generated by the switch and the "rotation" by $\zeta_n$).  Together these mean that it has degree exactly $2n$, with the Galois group that you have identified.

This is one of the rare cases in which it's easier to compute Galois group than the degree first. Without considering the Galois group, it's not easy to show $x^{2n}-(t^n+t^{-n})x+1$ is irreducible.
We only need a simple fact: given any field $F$, and transcendental elements $t, s$ there is a unique isomorphism $\rho: F(t)\rightarrow F(s)$, such that $\rho|_F=\text{id}_F$ and $\rho(t)=s$.
Therefore there exists $\rho\in \text{Gal}(\mathbb C(t) | \mathbb C)$, such that $$\rho(t)=\zeta t^i$$ where $\zeta$ is an $n$-th root of unity, and $i=\pm 1$. We remark that it's easy to see $\zeta t^i$ is indeed transcendental over $\mathbb C$, and though the above fact only gives us an isomorphism to $\mathbb C(\zeta t^i)$, we do have $\mathbb C(\zeta t^i)=\mathbb C(t)$, therefore $\rho$ is indeed in the Galois group.
Note that each $\rho$ must fix $t^n + t^{-n}$. Therefore, we have shown that $$\big|\text{Gal}(\mathbb C(t)|\mathbb C(t^n+t^{-n}))\big|\ge 2n$$
On the other hand, from the polynomial $x^{2n}-(t^n+t^{-n})x+1$, we know that
$$[\mathbb C(t):\mathbb C(t^n+t^{-n})]\le 2n$$
By the well-known relation $\big|\text{Gal}(\mathbb C(t)|\mathbb C(t^n+t^{-n}))\big|\le [\mathbb C(t):\mathbb C(t^n+t^{-n})]$ and equality holds iff the extension is Galois, we must have the extension is Galois of degree $2n$. And using the implicit description $t\mapsto \zeta t^i$, it's easy to see that the Galois group is isomorphic to
$$U_n\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\simeq D_{n}$$
where $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ acts on $U_n:=\{\zeta:\zeta^N=1\}$ such that the nontrivial element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ send $\zeta$ to $\frac{1}{\zeta}$.

Thanks a lot, very clear explanation.

I am a bit confused by the last semidirect product. Suppose we want to compose $(\zeta, -1)\cdot (\zeta,1)$. Then by our rule we get $(\zeta\cdot \zeta^{-1}, -1)=(1,-1)$. But the actual composition of maps gives us $t\mapsto \zeta^2t^{-1}$.

@JunXu Thanks for the careful reading. In an "internal semidirect product", comma should be understood as multiplication, so $(\zeta, -1)$ represents $t\mapsto (\zeta t)^{-1}$, not $t\mapsto \zeta t^{-1}$. Perhaps I should have written $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\ltimes U_n$ to avoid the confusion, in which case, $(-1, \zeta)$ indeed represents $t\mapsto \zeta t^{-1}$.
